# OnSwipeTouchListener not found

Tags: java, android, kotlin, swipe-gesture, android-gesture

I'm trying to work on Swipe Gestures in android. And to swipe below is the code

```
viewid.setOnTouchListener(OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
            override public void onSwipeTop() {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
...

        });
```

But, `OnSwipeTouchListener` is not found in kotlin. What to do ?

Comment: `OnSwipeTouchListener` doesn't exist for Java or Koltin. Are you using some library?

Comment: Check out this link, You can create a custom class this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938787/5097842

Comment: Yeah I'm using Fling for swipe. Thank you